# adding namespaced twig paths

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml, symfony4

I would like to use bootstrap 4 CoreUi template in my symfony project.
I added it to my project with

> composer require coreui/coreui

Now coreui is in my vendor directory, I would like to add a path in twig.yaml to simplify its access, according to [the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html) I modified my twig.yaml file like this :

```
twig:
#    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    paths:
        - '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
        - '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/coreui': coreui
```

I get an ErrorException :

> Notice: Undefined index: value

The doc doesn't say much... so I don't know what to do at this point.

Comment: Does "bin/console debug:twig" run?  Look carefully at the [multiple paths](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-configurable-trailing-slash-on-imported-routes) example. See the difference?

Comment: I do, but I want to keep the default templates path, if I remove the dash, I have an other issue saying that my yaml file is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for posting the wrong link in my comments.  The error you are getting is a twig "feature".  Basicially just need to supply a value for the blank namespace.

```
twig:
   #paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    paths:
       #'%kernel.project_dir%/templates': '' # add : ''
        '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/coreui': coreui
```

Run bin/console debug:twig and all should be well.

Update: Based on the discussion below with @yceruto as well as this [github issue](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/pull/434), I changed the answer to simply comment out the default templates line.  Turns out it is not needed and there is a pull request to remove it.  Always wondered why it was there in the first place.

Comment: adding `'%kernel.project_dir%/templates'` to the `paths` config is not necessary, it's already added through `default_path` config since Symfony 3.4. And the correct `null` namespace should be `~` instead of empty string `''`.

Comment: @yceruto With respect to tilde vs empty, the end result is the same.  I kind of think '' is easier to understand in this instance.  Removing the default templates directory has the rather interesting side effect of moving the "None" namespace lines to the bottom of the search order.  This will makes it challenging to override vendor templates.  Not really sure why it changes the order but it does.  Not something I would recommend messing with.

Comment: Yes, same result because the way TwigBundle checks empty namespaces `!$namespace` but I could misinterpret that a blank namespace means "no namespace" which is wrong in Twig context.

Comment: About the namespace order, it doesn't matter, only the order of the paths within each namespace matter in the overriding mechanism.

Comment: @yceruto I fear we may be getting a bit off topic here but just out of curiosity,  why does the "out of the box" twig.yaml file include a paths section is the first place?   You seem to be arguing that it not necessary at all.

Comment: Yes, defining "again" the default path in paths section has some drawback, see discussion/proposal here https://github.com/symfony/recipes/pull/434, paths section should be used for additional paths only.

Comment: @yceruto Thanks for the info.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`paths:` is getting two parameters as `array`, here

`%kernel.project_dir%/templates` and `%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/coreui` are directories must be exists, if not exists you need to create or just remove if don't need one of.

Mine is like that:

```
twig:
    paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
```